# Building an 12 x12 matrix from an expression taking 4 indices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to get the output

[image: matrix]

from the code

```
Do[
  Print[
    Flatten[Table[j + k + s + l, {j, -1, 1}, {k, -2, 1}]]], 
  {s, -1, 1}, {l, -2, 1}]
```

Comment: Check [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Do` and `Print`; use `Table` with `Flatten` or maybe `ArrayReshape`.

```
m =
  Flatten[
    Table[
      Flatten[Table[j + k + s + l, {j, -1, 1}, {k, -2, 1}]],
      {s, -1, 1}, {l, -2, 1}],
    1]

m // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

```
m = 
  ArrayReshape[
    Table[j + k + s + l, {j, -1, 1}, {k, -2, 1}, {s, -1, 1}, {l, -2, 1}], 
    {12, 12}]
```

will give the same result with `MatrixForm` but requires explicitly giving the dimensions of the array to be built.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent output:

```
Array[Plus, {3, 4, 3, 4}, {-1, -2, -1, -2}] ~Flatten~ {{3, 2}, {1, 4}}
```

Or for the particular case illustrated:

```
Array[Plus, {3, 4, 3, 4}] ~Flatten~ {{3, 2}, {1, 4}} - 10
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 -6 & -5 & -4 & -3 & -5 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 \\
 -5 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 \\
 -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 -5 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 \\
 -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$